# How do best iterate over a queryset with a changing id?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to increase the performance of a part of my application. The easiest way to handle the logic is the least friendly to the database. The more code I write, the more I feel I'm overcomplicating the situation.

**Poor Performing (for obvious reasons)**

```py
ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10]

for id in ids:
    results = MyTable.objects.filter(id=id)

    for item in results:
        doProcessing(item)
```

My ids list can get large pretty easily, which of course results in a bunch of hits to the database. However, I know easily that list of results are only for the specified id.

**Trying to Improve (unsuccessfully)**

```py
ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10]
results = MyTable.objects.filter(id__in=ids)

for item in results:
   doProcessing(item)
```

That is the basic of what I'm trying to do. But obviously the iteration is going to give me all the results for all of the ids. I still need to be able to process all of the results that have the same id as a group.

In the end I think I still need a list with the results for a given id. I then process that entire list, then move on to the next list.

I just can't find a clean way of separating out those groups of results with the same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Django ORM doesn't directly expose a way to do this that I can think of, but if you have the database do the sorting for you you can at least get your items pre-grouped in your queryset.

I would therefore do this by using [itertools.groupy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to handle organizing the values with the same id into a shared iterable, after using `.order_by(id)` on the queryset to group the elements by id:

```
import itertools
import operator

ordered_results = MyTable.objects.filter(id__in=ids).order_by('id')
for (shared_id, items) in itertools.groupby(ordered_results, operator.attrgetter('id')):
    # whatever your per-group processing is here
```